sigaction vs sigwait for graceful termination
I have a multithreaded application that I want to implement graceful termination in.
So far, I've used sigaction to call a signal handler that uses a semaphore to let the main and other threads know it's time for shutdown. The reason for using sempahores is that semaphores are async-signal-safe, so I can use them inside the signal handler without issue.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <errno.h>

// Semaphores are one of the few appropriate sync mechanisms that are async-signal-safe
sem_t signalSemaphore;

void signalHandler(int signal) {
  sem_post(&signalSemaphore);
}

void start_threads() {
  printf("Starting threads!\n");
}

void stop_threads() {
  printf("Stopping threads\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (sem_init(&signalSemaphore, 0, 0)) {
    perror("Unable to init semaphore");
    return 1;
  }

  struct sigaction newAction;
  newAction.sa_handler = signalHandler;
  sigemptyset(&newAction.sa_mask);
  newAction.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &newAction, NULL);
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &newAction, NULL);

  start_threads();

  for(;;) {
    if(sem_wait(&signalSemaphore)) {
      if(errno != EINTR) {
        // EINTR will be triggered when receiving a signal, so if not that, it's bad
        perror("Error while waiting for semaphore");
        return 1;
      }
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  stop_threads();

  if(sem_destroy(&signalSemaphore)) {
    perror("Error destroying semaphore");
    return 1;
  }
}

A seemingly simpler way to handle graceful termination could be to block SIGINT and SIGTERM (the two signals I want to capture for graceful termination) and use sigwait to wait for these signals to pop up. This saves me from setting the semaphore and signal handlers. The main reason behind wanting this alternative approach is that macOS does not support semaphores, which makes my original code less portable.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

void stop_threads() {
  printf("Stopping threads!\n");
}

void start_threads() {
  printf("Starting threads\n");
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  start_threads();

  sigset_t sigset;
  sigemptyset(&sigset);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGINT);
  sigaddset(&sigset, SIGTERM);
  sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &sigset, NULL);

  // Wait until one of the signals is pending (generated but not delivered)
  int sig;
  if(sigwait(&sigset, &sig)) {
    perror("Error calling sigwait");
  }

  stop_threads();
}

The question is, are there any downsides to using sigwait instead of sigaction and writing a signal handler?
Thanks!

I don't understand what you're proposing to do with sigwait(). Is every thread going to call sigwait() periodically? I think only one of them will receive the signal, how will the other threads know to shutdown?

Please show a [mre] of what you want to do.

Apologies, will edit the question with an example of both cases

I have an issue with your first sentence.  Do you have an ovrerriding need for umm.. 'graceful termination', (which is often, as in this case, leads to 'far from graceful 'code), rather than just terminating your process and have your OS zap everything?

I have to flush database transactions and close it so I kinda do have an overriding need for graceful termination. That said, whether I need graceful termination or not was not part of my question, I just want to know if there's any downsides to the sigwait approach

I don't understand why you need a semaphore. The usual approach is to have a variable of type volatile sig_atomic_t that is modified in your signal handler and checked in your main processing loop. I suggest to [edit] your question and show a [mre] that uses at least one additional thread.

@Bodo sig_atomic_t is not guaranteed to be async-signal-safe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32349278/is-stdatomic-signal-safe
Also, I'm not asking about sig_atomic_t  vs semaphores. I'm specifically asking about signal handler (via sigaction) vs sigwait

@ImanolBarbaSabariego Is std::atomic the same as sig_atomic_t? See https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/sig_atomic_t "An integer type which can be accessed as an atomic entity even in the presence of asynchronous interrupts made by signals."

One drawback of sigwait is that it suspends the thread, so this thread cannot do any other work. Your question might be an XY problem.

Yeah, this is intended, as I'm putting sigwait on the main thread which would otherwise be blocked doing thread join. The sigwait goes just before the cleanup code (which afterwards does the thread join).
The problem here is doing proper graceful exit when catching SIGINT/TERM, which involves dealing with async-signal-safe mechanisms. I have tried several solutions in the past: atomic variables, pipes, semaphores, etc. I have already solved the problem. I just want to know the drawbacks between ONE of my approaches vs another specific one. Thanks

It is difficult to answer the question without knowing all details about your application. Please [edit] your question to add more information, explanations, reasoning etc. In your question you wrote "The main reason behind wanting this alternative approach is that macOS does not support semaphores, which makes my original code less portable." So you stated this as the real problem you want to solve.
